# How to make conditional SQL join

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have the following tables with their insert script:

```
    DECLARE @A TABLE
    (
      [ID] INT IDENTITY,
      [SID] INT 
    )


DECLARE @EP TABLE
    (
      [SID] INT ,
      [RID] INT ,
      [HR] INT
    )

DECLARE  @XR TABLE
    (
      [SID] INT ,
      [RID] INT ,
      [UID] INT
    )

DECLARE @SR TABLE
    (
      [RID] INT ,
      [RNAME] VARCHAR(10),
      [SID] INT
    )


INSERT INTO @A
SELECT 1 UNION 
SELECT 2


INSERT INTO  @EP
SELECT 1, 1, 1 UNION   
SELECT 1, 2, 1 UNION
SELECT 1, 3, 1 UNION
SELECT 2, 4, 1 UNION
SELECT 2, 5, 1 UNION
SELECT 2, 6, 1 

INSERT INTO  @XR
SELECT 1, 1, 1 UNION   
SELECT 1, 2, 1 UNION
SELECT 1, 2, 2 UNION
SELECT 2, 4, 1 UNION
SELECT 2, 5, 2 

INSERT INTO @SR
SELECT 1,'Apple', 1 UNION
SELECT 2,'Mango', 1 UNION
SELECT 3,'Banana',1 UNION
SELECT 4,'Apple', 2 UNION
SELECT 5,'Mango', 2 UNION
SELECT 6,'Banana',2
```

When I am running the following SQL query, I get two output rows which is fine:

```
DECLARE @UD INT 
SET @UD=1

SELECT * FROM @A A
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT 1                      
    FROM   @EP [EP]                      
    INNER JOIN @XR XR ON [EP].SID = A.SID 
    WHERE  [EP].SID = A.SID                     
    AND [EP].RID = XR.RID  
    AND [EP].[HR] = 1                      
    AND XR.UID = @UD
)
--OUTPUT
--ID          SID
------------- -----------
--1           1
--2           2
```

But when I run the above query with "@UD=3" I get no record. I want to put a conditional join here which should look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM @A A
--IF((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @XR XR WHERE XR.XR=A.SID)>0) 
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT 1                      
    FROM   @EP [EP]                      
    INNER JOIN @XR XR ON [EP].SID = A.SID 
    WHERE  [EP].SID = A.SID                     
    AND [EP].RID = XR.RID  
    AND [EP].[HR] = 1                      
    AND XR.UID = @UD
)
--ELSE
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT 1                      
    FROM   @EP [EP]                      
    INNER JOIN @SR SR ON SR.SID = A.SID 
    WHERE  [EP].SID = A.SID                     
    AND [EP].RID = SR.RID  
    AND [EP].[HR] = 1                      
    AND SR.[RNAME] = 'Banana'
)
```

The abover query should return the two rows for both @UID 1 and 3 i.e if there is no record found @XR for particular uid it should go for else loop. Can you help me resolve this issue? I won't like to go for **union** here and would like to do the same in **SINGLE** query with conditions in *joins* only and not writing the external if and else loops.

Comment: r u looking for an outer join ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM @A A
WHERE ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @XR XR WHERE XR.XR=A.SID)=0 AND EXISTS(
    SELECT 1                      
    FROM   @EP [EP]                      
    INNER JOIN @XR XR ON [EP].SID = A.SID 
    WHERE  [EP].SID = A.SID                     
    AND [EP].RID = XR.RID  
    AND [EP].[HR] = 1                      
    AND XR.UID = @UD
)) OR ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @XR XR WHERE XR.XR=A.SID)!=0 AND EXISTS(
    SELECT 1                      
    FROM   @EP [EP]                      
    INNER JOIN @SR SR ON SR.SID = A.SID 
    WHERE  [EP].SID = A.SID                     
    AND [EP].RID = SR.RID  
    AND [EP].[HR] = 1                      
    AND SR.[RNAME] = 'Banana'
))
```

i.e. just combine the two with a simple boolean. You might not need the second COUNT(*) query BTW.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it, if I am understanding the requirement correctly:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    A.* 
FROM @A AS A
JOIN @EP AS EP ON A.SID = EP.SID
LEFT JOIN @XR AS XR ON EP.RID = XR.RID
LEFT JOIN @SR AS SR ON  SR.SID = A.SID
WHERE EP.HR = 1
    AND (XR.UID = @UD OR RNAME IS NOT NULL)
```